# SPFx web part throwing error in SP2019

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, deployment, 2019

I have created spfx solution by selecting option which will work in SP Online and SP 2019. I have tested this in SP Online which is working fine.

Now I have moved this .sppkg file to SP 2019 app catalog. While adding app to app catalog it is showing as below. It is getting content from SP Online. 
[image]

In write-manifest.json file I have left the default values

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/write-manifests.schema.json",
  "cdnBasePath": "<!-- PATH TO CDN -->"
}
```

Now I have installed the app to app catalog then added web part to the page. I haven't modified the OOB web part which comes while creating the web part using yomen generator. I have selected React as framework for this.

But it is throwing below error after I have added web part to page
[image]

Is this because of the `write-manifest.json` file's `cdnBasePath` value?
Package.json

```
{
  "name": "custom-solutions",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/react": "16.4.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-core": "^10.1.0",
    "react": "16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "16.3.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "16.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.4.1",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you paste the `package.json` file ? SP 2019 supports only 1.4.1 version of SPFx

Comment: updated with package.json

Comment: @GautamSheth, 16.3.2 related to react framework right!! This will be an issue?

Comment: yes React 16 is the main issue here as well as other internal stuff. Should work with the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its buggy `package.json` created by the yeoman generator,

SP 2019 as mentioned supports version `1.4.0` of SPFx which is based on React 15.

Would suggest that you modify the `package.json` as below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "15.6.2",
    "@types/react": "15.6.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.6",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.4.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33"
  },  
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "1.4.1",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/chai": ">=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
    "@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2"
  }
```

and also, ensure that your `tsconfig.json` is as below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@microsoft"
    ],
    "types": [
      "es6-promise",
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom",
      "es2015.collection"
    ]
  }
}
```

After that, delete your `node_modules` folder and install the packages again using `npm i` and check. It should work both in SP 2019 and SPO as well since SPO is always backwards compatible.

Comment: I see that change you made in `tsconfig.json` file is `"module": "esnext"` to `"module": "commonjs"`  and you have removed `"moduleResolution": "node"`.

Comment: Can you tell me about these properties more!!

Comment: not an expert on these unfortunately :( I pasted the working older version from an old SPFx webpart and it looks like in the newer versions the properties have might which might not work in SP 2019. Is it working now at your end ?

Comment: Trying it.. i will let you know

Comment: After this change it is giving me below error when I do `gulp serve`: This site can’t provide a secure connection

Comment: I guess `"@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.4.0",` value should be `"@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.4.1",` isn't it?

Comment: Could be, can you try that?

Comment: After changing value to `"@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.4.1"` it is working fine in online also in on-premises. Please update the answer also for future reference